# YAML unmarshal error cannot unmarshal !!str ` ` to str

Tags: manifest, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push my Spring Boot application on Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) via `manifest.yml` file.

While pushing the app i am getting the following error:

```
{ 
Pushing from manifest to org mastercard_connect / space developer-sandbox as e069875...

Using manifest file C:\Sayli\Workspace\PCF\healthwatch-api\healthwatch-api\manifest.yml

yaml: unmarshal errors:

line 6: cannot unmarshal !!str `healthw...` into []string
FAILED }
```

Here is the `manifest.yml` file:

```
{applications:
- name: health-watch-api

memory: 2GB

instances: 1

paths: healthwatch-api-jar\target\healthwatch-api-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

services: healthwatch-api-database 
  }
```

Comment: Your manifest file is invalid. Please see - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html for the example of the manifest file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your manifest is not valid. The link @K.AJ posted is a good reference.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

Here's an example, which uses the values from your file.

```
---
applications:
- name: health-watch-api
  memory: 2G
  path: healthwatch-api-jar/target/healthwatch-api-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  services:
  - healthwatch-api-database
```

You don't need the leading/trailing `{` `}`'s, it's `path` not `paths` and `services` is an array. I think the last one is what the cli is complaining about the most.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while using Pulumi, using GitHub Actions. The cause was not having a Variable available in the GH yaml config. This resulted in the value that I was trying to add to `pulumi.dev.yaml` being added as 'null'; after correcting this issue, I could see the correct value.